# rank of these two matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Could anyone confirm me that rank of these two matrices are $3$ or not? Thanks!

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&1&0\\0&2&2&-1\\1&2&3&0\\0&-1&0&2\end{pmatrix}, \quad N=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&-3&0\\0&2&0&-1\\-3&-1&1&2\\-2&-2&0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

After doing several time elementary row operation I have got following matrices:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&1&0\\0&2&2&-1\\0&0&2&3\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \quad N=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\0&2&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: If you really just want a yes or no, Wolfram Alpha can do this.

Comment: Yes, Wolfram Alpha [can](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+rank&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22MatrixOperations%22,+%22theMatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B3,0,1,0%7D,%7B0,2,2,-1%7D,%7B1,2,3,0%7D,%7B0,-1,0,2%7D%7D%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,+%22%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D). And both ranks are in fact 3.

Comment: If your row ops are right, one more division by lead coefficients puts them in row reduced echelon form, both have rank 3.

Comment: @coffeemath Why bother with reducing? It's already in row echelon form, and you can clearly see the pivots even without dividing.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you're right. I only was suggesting that *if* one goes all the way to row reduced, it is just to find the dimension of the upper left identity matrix which ends up appearing in that form. (I also forgot to mention the other row ops necessary to get to row reduced, to make 0 above and below leading 1's) But definitely there is no need to go all the way to row reduced anyway, as you note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already been noted in comments that Wolfram|Alpha can perform this check.

Alternatively, if you want to do it by hand, it's not too much effort to calculate the determinants of these matrices by row or column expansion, due to the many zeros. The determinants are both $0$, so the rank is less than $4$. It's easy to find three linearly independent rows or columns in either matrix, so the rank is at least $3$. Thus the rank is $3$.